# Operator norm of Fourier transform operator

Tags: operator-theory, fourier-transform

It may be trivial, but I am thinking the best way to show operator norm of Fourier transform operator on $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ i.e. show $\Arrowvert T \Arrowvert =\frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^{N/2}}$.

Since we already known $||T||\leq \frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^{N/2}}$, it suffices to show the other direction. I'm trying to find $\exists u \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\frac{\Arrowvert Tu \Arrowvert}{\Arrowvert u \Arrowvert} = \frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^{N/2}}$. I'm trying to construct a sequence of integrable function that converges to the delta function and then the Fourier transform of the delta function is $\frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^{N/2}}$. However, this is in the sense of distributions. Is there any more rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: F.T. is not an operator on $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$. Its range is not contained in $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$. You have to specify the range sapce before you can talk about its norm.

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention T maps $L^1$ to $C_0$ Which is vanishing at infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are considering $T$  as an operator from $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n})$ into the space $C_0(\mathbb R^{n})$ of continuous functions vanishing at $\infty$ with the sup norm. The norm of $T$ (which is $(2\pi)^{-N/2}$) is attained at the function $(2\pi)^{-N/2} e^{-\|x\|^{2} /2}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. The Gaussian function works pretty well. For coefficient is equal to 1/2, the Fourier transform has the property that $T(u)=u$.